# I get error in my function using jshint?

Tags: javascript

Here is my function:-

```
function setLangCookie() {
  "use strict";
    var value = "FR";
    var expiredays = 1825;
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + expiredays);
    document.cookie = "lang=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays == null) ? "" : ";path=/;expires=" + exdate.toGMTString());
}
```

Errors:

> Line 7: `document.cookie = "lang=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays == null) ? "" : ";path=/;expires=" + exdate.toGMTString());`
>
> Expected `'==='` and instead saw `'=='`.
>
> Line 7: `document.cookie = "lang=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays == null) ? "" : ";path=/;expires=" + exdate.toGMTString());`

`'escape'` is not defined.

Comment: yes, this is your script and that are your hints. What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

You're in `strict mode`. You have to access the window object's properties using the prefix `window.`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.escape

Comment: how to define and resolve it ..

Comment: @NarendraPatel Use `window.escape` instead, since it's a global function.

Comment: Thanks to all. resolved all errors...

Answer (score 1):

It wants you to use `window.escape` instead of just `escape`.

I would also assume it would yell at you for not using triple equals with the null check, if you are using the default settings.

```
function setLangCookie() {
  "use strict";
    var value = "FR";
    var expiredays = 1825;
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + expiredays);
    document.cookie = "lang=" + window.escape(value) + ((expiredays === null) ? "" : ";path=/;expires=" + exdate.toGMTString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from escape not being defined, the complaint about seeing '==' instead of '===' relates to the way that Javascript treats equality.  '===' requires the two compared values to be of the same type, where '==' will do type coercion to get equality.

In most cases you really want to use '===' instead because it prevents subtle bugs, such as `0` being treated as `false`.